# Set Nexus repository in build.gradle for android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, maven-2, nexus, sonatype

I would like to set a nexus repo in my gralde config to access some local libraries.

Do I need to set the nexus repo in my gradle config like following ?

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "http://mySuperRepo/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }

    jcenter()
}
```

I have already set the nexus in the maven config file (settings.xml in m2)

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>proxy.host.com</host>
        <port>8081</port>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <nonProxyHosts>nonProxyHost.net</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>

<servers>
    <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <username>useeeername</username>
            <password>passwoooord</password>
    </server>
</servers>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
            <id>idMyMirror</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://mySuperRepo/nexus/public/</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

My problem is that AndroidStudio seems to download all the nexus repo in my laptop. The .AndroidStudio/ folder take 48Gb. If I delete this folder, the next time I open android studio everything is downloaded again.

Do you have a solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

It should NOT download everything from the repo. Just what is needed and it can't find in the local Maven repository. Gradle does not take your Maven settings file into account at all, but in your case it will download artifacts from the local repo.

If you are not using Maven at all I would remove the local Maven repository (~/.m2/repository) and the reference to it in your build.gradle file.

In any case though the downloads are done by AndroidStudio and Gradle and cached in the local cache of Gradle in ~/.gradle/caches and it should only download whatever is needed. 48GB seems excessive and might be a gradle or AndroidStudio configuration or bug that causes it. Unless of course your project really is that complex.

The fact that so much is downloaded has nothing to do with Nexus and is completely related to the client side tooling. You might also want to configure jcenter as a proxy repository in Nexus rather than referencing it directly in the build.gradle file.

Comment: My bad, actually this is the folder ".AndroidStudio" which take 48Gb. I edited my first post. Android studio show a task named "processing indices" or "processing indexes" when it download everything in this folder.

Comment: These might be the Maven index files that are exposed by Nexus and other repository servers. It should be optional to download them. The are only used for local search and such. You dont require them.

Comment: Yes, It seems to not be mandatory to have theses files on the hard drive, but Androi studio always download them. It takes a large space on the drive...

Comment: I would suggest to file a bug with the Android Studio team or at least ask them for some sort of configuration option or help figuring out whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

put this URL in `build.gradle` in android studio

```
maven { url 'nexus-server/repository/gradle/' }
maven { url 'nexus-server/repository/mvn/' }
```

where in nexus server
mvn repository is [https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/"](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/%22)
and gradle repository is https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).